# Clone Opportunity via Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity, automation, clone

Using [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004893&language=en_US&type=1)  I have the following apex on a visualforce page,that I want to run when a user saves the opportunity as **'won'**.

My questions are:

**1. How do I add it as a popup  when the user saves the opportunity?**

**2. How do I re-direct the user to that new Opportunity after it has been created?**

```
<apex:page standardController='Opportunity'>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock title='clone opportunity' mode='edit'>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title='Please Click below to clone this quote' columns='1'>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:pageBlockButtons >

    <apex:commandButton value='Clone' action='{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.Clone,<Opportunity>.id)}'/>

                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and is working perfectly fine with one modification >
Just remode angular brackets here `{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.Clone,<Opportunity>.id)}`
And you are good to go !

```
<apex:page standardController='Opportunity'>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title='clone opportunity' mode='edit'>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title='Please Click below to clone this quote' columns='1'>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value='Clone' action='{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.Clone,Opportunity.id)}'/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Updated to your comment : 
yes the code will work completely fine according to your criteria > 
i applied if on the *apex:pageblockbuttons* and it is working fine.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="clone opportunity" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Please Click below to clone this quote" columns="1"> </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons rendered="{!IF(Opportunity.StageName=='Closed Won',true,false)}">
                <apex:commandButton value="Clone" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.Clone,Opportunity.id)}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for that - glad there was only a slight mistake... How do I achieve the 2 questions above? I am trying to add this to the code `rendered="{!IF(Opportunity.StageName=='Closed Won',true,false}"/ >` is that correct?

Comment: I have updated the answer for your requirement @CoolAdminGuy